Express server creating port file when starting
I am using the node v20.12.2 version in my application and starting my express server. But when I start my server it creates a file of port(5004;) like the file in my project folder and when I restart the server it gives me Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 5004; this type of error. This problem occurs whenever I start the server. How do we overcome this problem?
package.json
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.js"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "mongoose": "^8.5.2",
    "winston": "^3.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.1.4"
  }
}

config/index.js
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

export const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8004

service/ExpressApp.js
import express from "express";
import routes from "../routes/index.js"

export default async (app) => {
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    app.use("/", routes)

    return app;
}

services/Database.js
import mongoose from 'mongoose'; 
import { MONGO_URI } from '../config/index.js';

export default async() => {

    try {
        await mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }

}
  
  

index.js
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import dbConnection from "./services/Database.js";
import App from "./services/ExpressApp.js";
import { PORT } from "./config/index.js";

dotenv.config();

const StartServer = async () => {
  const app = express();
  app.use(cors());

  await dbConnection();

  await App(app);

  app.use("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "App is running",
    });
  });

  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
  });
};

StartServer();


Since you're not posting the actual file that contains the PORT variable, I'm going to hazard a guess: it contains this:
PORT=5004;

Remove the semicolon (;).

Thanks for sorting the issue I have correct my env file with the semicolon after the port in.env file
